# How to add an argument to a service which will be parsed as a privider in a component's constructor?

Tags: angular

I have this service as a provider:

```js
export class Print {
  text: string;

  constructor(text: string) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  printText() {
    //dosomething with the text;
  }

  prettifyText() {
    //dosomething with the text;
  }
}
```

In my component, I'd like to parse in the `text` as argument upon angular make an instance of the provider.

```js
const text = 'Something to be printed';

export class AppComponent {
  // How to parse 'text' as an argument
  // to the printService when it is instantiate 
  // by angular componennt?
  constructor(printService: Print) {
    printService.prettifyText();
    printServoce.printText();
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's the `text` coming from in your component?

Comment: Say it's some global text (a config file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought, question is how to provide constructor values in Injected ( provided ) service. If you need that, that is more advanced, consider this:

```
@Injectable()
export class Print {
 text: string;

 constructor(text: string) {
    this.text = text;
    let injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
    let http = injector.get(Http);

    http
        .get(this.text + ".json")
        .subscribe(
            (response: any) => this.text = response.text(), // success
            null, // error
            () => console.log("c")// complete
        );
 }
}
```

Injector is from angular2/core, Http and HTTP_PROVIDERS are from angular2/http
In your component decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector : "cmp-name",
  providers: [provide(Print, { useFactory: () => { return new
Print("hello"); }})]
})
```

And in constructor of cmp-name

```
constructor(public print: Print) {}
```

If you console.log print, you will get:

```
Print {text: "hello"}
```

Comment: Actually this is the right answer, as the printText() method shouldn't take argument by design. I have learnt this advanced technique. Thanks!

Comment: How do I use http service inside of the `useFactory: () => {}` if I want to get the config.json from a local/remote server?

Comment: You must make that call with text value?

Comment: Ok, i improved answer, and hopefully you need that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have `text` available in your component, once you do you can call your service's methods:

```
export class AppComponent {
  text;
  constructor(private printService: Print, private http: Http) {
    // you can get text through http, for example
    this.http
      .get('story.txt')
      .subscribe(
        response => this.text = response.text(), // success
        null, // error
        () => this.print() // complete
      )
  }
  print() {
    this.printService..printText(this.text)
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the better structure, I do need to refactor my code.

Comment: you're welcome (; try to avoid doing things from the constructor, use it to set up stuff only, and move your app logic to other places.

Comment: The Angular [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) suggests keeping "complex logic out of the constructor, especially anything that might call a server.  The constructor is for simple initializations like wiring constructor parameters to properties."  So I suggest putting http calls in `ngOnInit()`.

Comment: @MarkRajcok yea, I mentioned this in comment above. My constructors are usually empty, I just used this to demonstrate; and when trying if things will work...